# python 3.x append a list and remove item from old list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there was a way of shorting this code by using a list comprehension. I have tried to use them by every time the loop runs the last ltems in the loop are all I get. This is what I tried.

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i[0] == counter]
```

Here is the code I want to improve.

```
list1 = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5),(8,6),(9,4)]
list2 = []
counter = 0

while counter != 10:
    for i in list1:
        if i[0] == counter:
            list2.append(i)

    for j in list2:
        if j in list1:
            list1.remove(j)

    counter += 1
```

Thank you for any help

Edit. I should have given a bit more code here. There will be another list that will get filled by list2 when the counter == i[1]. I have used this list comprehension to replace the for loop used to remove items from list1

```
list1[:] = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
```

What I want to know is there any way of using a list comprehension (or something I have not seen before) that could get the for loop used to append the lists down to one line?

```
list1 = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5),(8,6),(9,4)]
list2 = []
list3 = []

counter = 0

while counter != 10:
    for i in list1:
        if i[0] == counter:
            list2.append(i)

    for j in list2:
        if j in list1:
            list1.remove(j)

    for x in list2:
        if x[1] == counter:
            list3.append(i)

    for y in list3:
        if y in list2:
            list1.remove(y)



    counter += 1
```

Comment: can you post an expected result for `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: Shouldn't `list1` be always empty in the end?

Comment: IMO, you can do it this way: `list2, list1 = list1[:11], list1[10:]`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you're just copying the elements of list 1 into list 2. Then trying to remove all the elements of list 1 if they are in list 2. Technically this can be accomplished with the following

```
list1 = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5),(8,6),(9,4)]
list2 = list1
list1 = []
```

But in the spirit of your question. The if statement you were using in your list comprehension is fine, but the value of counter is never incremented so you were always testing if `i[0] == 0` which was never true.

If you are just trying to learn about how list comprehensions behave then what you were probably trying to accomplish can be done with the following

```
list1 = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5),(8,6),(9,4)]
list2 = [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
list1 = [val for val in list2 if val not in list1]
```

The first list comprehension is similar to using a counter. The second is a for each loop with a condition and is much more pythonic than the first. Not exactly sure what your intent is for this code, but hope this helps.

Comment: you shouldn't ever need to do that `list2 = [list1[i] ... ]` list comp. `list2 = list1` is equivalent, and even if you needed to filter on something you could do `list1 = [el for el in list1 if ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
list1 = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5),(8,6),(9,4)]
list2 = []
counter = 0

for counter, (x, y) in list(enumerate(list1)):
    list2.append((x, y))
    list1.remove((x, y))
```

Comment: ick why do this? `list.remove` is very expensive, `counter` is never used, and you don't have to cast `enumerate(...)` to list.

Comment: I tried to make the exact starting situation shorter, as it was asked. I did it in a few seconds after it was asked, and was not looking for optimization. You are right, but that's the why.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found an answer for my question if you use += instead of = in the list comprehension the list is append instead of replaced. Will only work if you declare the list before you run the comprehension. Thank you everyone for the answers.

```
list1 = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5),(8,6),(9,4)]
list2 = []
list3 = []

counter = 0

while counter != 10:
    list2 += [n for n in list1 if n[0] == counter]

    list1 = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]

    list3 += [j for j in list2 if j[1] == counter]

    list2 = [n for n in list2 if n not in list2] 

counter += 1
```

Comment: I'm certain there's a better algorithm for this. Can you inverse sort `list1` by its first element, increment up, and append the popped element when it matches counter?

Comment: plus what the heck is `list2 = [n for n in list2 if n not in list2]` supposed to do??

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way to do this that I can find is

```
list1.sort(lambda t: t[0], reverse=True)
list2 = []

for i in range(10):
    while list1[-1][0] == i:
        # grab all the items from list1 where x == i (in tuples (x, y) )
        list2.append(list1.pop())
```

In this case a list comprehension is really not preferred.